# "Take the 2018 Developer Survey" redirects to an old question

Tags: bug

The link to '*Take the 2018 Developer Survey*' in the 'Frequently Asked' section of the meta homepage points to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/22/take-the-2018-developer-survey which redirects to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/should-a-user-have-only-one-account-on-all-so-serverfault-meta-sites/22#22) to a really old question.

[image: 'Take the 2018 Developer Survey' link]

This was initially quite confusing, especially because you end up mid-way down the page.

The correct link should replace ID 22 with 361588.

Comment: I've pinged the CMs about this, this is not something us mods can fix :-/

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks!